# ST_LineToCurve and ST_ForceCurve

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a set of LineStrings that I used to merge with ST_Collect. I want my lines to be curved, so I tried to use St_LineToCurve but my features were still MULTILIGNESTRING. I tried to *smooth* them on geoserver with stroke-linejoin: round but that didn't work.

I read it's possible to force lines to be curved with ST_ForceCurve. My geometries are now a MULTICURVE type, but GeoServer doesn't seem to handle it :

> Rendering process failed
>   java.io.IOExceptionorg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR:
>   lwgeom_simplify: unsupported geometry type: MultiCurve ERREUR:
>   lwgeom_simplify: unsupported geometry type: MultiCurve

Is there a way to curve my multilinestrings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go in GeoServer, open the postgis data store configuration, scroll down, disable geometry simplification.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have the error anymore, but my line are still not curved, even with MULTICURVE. I guess when it doesn't want to curve, it doesn't curve ;)

Comment: Not curved in which protocol/request/output format? For example GML 2 used by WFS 1.0 does not support curves, but GML 3 used by WFS 1.1 does.

Comment: I can't say.. I learn GIS by myself so I don't really understand every notions. I import WKT into postgis, convert them with ST_GeomFromText and then try to curve them. I don't understand why you mention WFS as I display my features with WMS..?

Comment: Oh, because I know that curves do remain curves in display with WMS, we have tests proving that. No idea why they don't in your case, if you have a reproducable test case, with sample data, style and a request, that shows the issue happening in GeoServer 2.9 and above (a supported version), I'd encourage you to open a bug report at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/summary

Comment: I didn't see that you're a geoserver dev. Thanks for your awesome job btw :)  I'll try to create a reproducible test case when I'll be sure that I'm not doing any wrong operations. Thanks !

Comment: Thank you, Best Answer, 
uncheck 
Support on the fly geometry simplification